# How can I handle time limit exceeded error in C?

Tags: c

You are in charge of the cake for your niece's birthday and have decided the cake will have one candle for each year of her total age. When she blows out the candles, she’ll only be able to blow out the tallest ones. Your task is to find out how many candles she can successfully blow out.

For example, if your niece is turning 4 years old, and the cake will have 4 candles of height 4, 4, 1, 3, she will be able to blow out 2 candles successfully, since the tallest candles are of height 4 and there are 2 such candles.

```
Constraints:
Age must be greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 100,000
Height of the candle must be greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 100,00,000
Sample Input:
4
3 2 1 3
Sample Output:
2
```

I came up with a code for this problem. But I was able to solve only two test cases. When the input is very large(age), it shows as error message as 'Time limit exceeded'.. Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100000
int main(){
    int n,i,j,cnt=1;
    long long a[N],temp;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(a[i]<a[j]){
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    if(a[i]==a[0]){
        cnt++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
printf("%d",cnt);
}
```

I'm not a very good programmer. I'm a student. I will be very happy with your help.

Comment: It is expecting an optimal solution for the given problem. If your solution is exceeding the time limit - it means that it is not fast enough and you should think about better one.

Comment: Some hints: No one asked you to sort all values. Also no one even asked you to keep all the values.

Comment: Even if you do want to sort, there are much faster sorting routines...

Comment: What is producing the error?

Comment: In truth, your final for loop, with one slight change will take care of this for you without the sorting...

Comment: SO only works if there is some feedback from the author. http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank You Sir. As a beginner, I feel like I don't have enough knowledge about DAA. Certainly, I will improve my code

Comment: @Gerhardh. Thank You sir.I understood where I went wrong. I'll post my new answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs in O(n^2) runtime, which is excessive for many problems.

Here is a solution with faster runtime, O(n). We check every element only once.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, a[1000000], i;
    printf("enter number of candles: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("enter the candle heights below\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    int maxnum = a[0], ans = 0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (a[i] == maxnum) ans++;
        if (a[i] > maxnum){
            maxnum = a[i];
            ans = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("answer: %d", ans);
}
```

As C and C++ are closely related, I'll keep the original **C++ version** of this solution here, if anybody finds helpful.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, temp;
    vector<int> a;
    cout << "enter number of candles: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "enter the candle heights below" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> temp;
        a.push_back(temp);
    }
    
    if (n == 0) cout << 0;
    int i, maxnum = a[0], ans = 0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (a[i] == maxnum) ans++;
        if (a[i] > maxnum){
            maxnum = a[i];
            ans = 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "answer: " << ans;
}
```

Tips: Another approach to this problem would be using a faster sorting algorithm, like - [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) / [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). They both have quicker runtime than what you're using ([Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)).

Comment: Offering a C++ solution to a C problem is of somewhat limited value.

Comment: Thanks, C version updated.